# About matrix derivative

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, derivatives

Suppose $A$ is a matrix with order n*n.

we have the following equity but I don't know why.

$f(x)=\frac{1}{2}x^TAx-b^Tx$.

then
$f'(x)=\frac{1}{2}A^Tx+\frac{1}{2}Ax-b$

Is there any rule like scalar function's derivative?

thanks.

Comment: Check out the matrix cookbook: http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/views/publication_details.php?id=3274

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way to see this is the following :

By definition, $f'(x)$ satisfies :

$$ f(x+h) = \color{blue}{f(x)} + h^{\top}\color{red}{f'(x)} + o(\Vert h \Vert)$$

So, by expanding $f(x+h)$, we get :

$$
\begin{align*}
f(x+h) &= {} \frac{1}{2}(x+h)^{\top}A(x+h)-b^{\top}(x+h) \\
 &= \Big[ \frac{1}{2} x^{\top}Ax - b^{\top}x \Big] + \Big[ \frac{1}{2} h^{\top}Ax+\frac{1}{2}x^{\top}Ah - b^{\top}h \Big] + \frac{1}{2} h^{\top}Ah \\
 &= \underbrace{\Big[ \frac{1}{2} x^{\top}Ax - b^{\top}x \Big]}_{\color{blue}{f(x)}} + h^{\top} \underbrace{\Big[ \frac{1}{2} Ax + \frac{1}{2} A^{\top}x - b \Big]}_{\color{red}{f'(x)}} + \underbrace{\frac{1}{2} h^{\top}Ah}_{o(\Vert h \Vert)}
\end{align*}
$$

As a consequence :

$$ f'(x) = \frac{1}{2} \big(A+A^{\top} \big)x - b $$

Comment: x is missing in the final eq

Comment: You're right !! Thanks!

Comment: wonderful explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to check it once really and then remember it :).

$$\begin{array}{rcl}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} f(x) &=& \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k = 1}^n\sum_{l = 1}^n A_{k,l}x_kx_l -\sum_{j = 1}^n b_j \\ &=& \frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{k = 1, k \neq i}^n (A_{k,i}x_k+A_{i,k}x_k)+2A_{i,i}x_i\right)-b_i\\ &=& \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k = 1}^n(A_{k,i}+A_{i,k})x_k-b_i  \\ &=& (\frac{1}{2}(A+A^T)x-b)_i.\end{array}$$

It follows that $$\nabla f(x)= \frac{1}{2}(A+A^T)x-b.$$

Comment: why did you $b_i$ term become positive?

Comment: @Bye_World It was typo obviously :), thanks for noticing it.

Comment: No problem.  Happy to help. (っ^‿^)っ

Comment: @Surb sorry I'm not a native English speaker,and I can only read English articles about Math,I didn't not quite catch the main idea about the question you recommand to me.If there is something offend you,would you like to forgive me?

Comment: I come here only for knowledge not offend somebody on purpose,you can advise me directly and I will accept it.@surb

Comment: @paradox No offense at all don't worry :). Furthermore I fully understand your situation since I'm not native english speaker too :). Anyway, when you ask a question and you get some answers, if one of them helped you to understand your problem and you think is a good answer then you may accept it by clicking on the $\sqrt{}$ under the upvote / downvote count. Note that there is no obligation to do it. But if you think there are complete and correct answer then you should accept your favorite one (also to show that the question has been answered).

Comment: But I still don't know what I did is wrong..